# How to make ng-model preview data to empty when the input field is hide from checkbox?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to make ng-model preview data to empty when the input field is hide from checkbox?
Here is my code

```
<div ng-app="">
<input id="eform_check" name="eform_check" type="checkbox" value="hide_input" onclick="showcheckbox();" >Hide input  

<p>Name : <input id="field" name="data" type="text" ng-model="name" style="inline-block"></p>  

<h1>{{name}}</h1>
<script>
function showcheckbox(){
  if(document.getElementById("eform_check").checked){ 
      document.getElementById('field').style.display =  'none';
      document.getElementById('field').value =  ''; 
    }else{
     document.getElementById('field').style.display =  'inline-block';    
    }
}
</script>
```

When user input something in the input box, it will show your input value.
but when user click the check box, the input value is destroy , but the AngularJS still keep the value here? how to make it disappear, THX

[image]
[image]
Here is Fiddle code, thx
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s10L6kvo/)

Comment: you have to make value disappear or destroy that value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the help of simple combination of **ng-model** and **ng-show** and your job done!

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"> Hide input  

<p>Name : <input type="text" ng-show="!checked" ng-model="name"></p>  

<h1 ng-show="!checked">{{name}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pure **AngularJS**, You can make use of `ng-model` on the checkbox which would toggle between true/false such as `ng-model="hide_input"`.

Now, depending on the value of the `hide_input`, you can show/hide the `input` control from the DOM using `ng-show` and more specifically use the `ng-if` to hide the preview.

Please note, that `ng-show` will only set the `display: none` to the element where as `ng-if` completely removes the element from the DOM.

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []).controller("ctrl", function($scope) {});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <input id="eform_check" name="eform_check" type="checkbox" ng-model="hide_input">Hide input

  <p>Name : <input id="field" name="data" type="text" ng-model="name" style="inline-block" ng-show="!hide_input" ng-cloak></p>
  <h1 ng-if="!hide_input">{{name}}</h1>
```

Comment: he doesn't want to show or hide value. his question is How to make ng-model preview data to empty when the input field is hidden from checkbox?

Comment: Its ambiguous, its not clear if the input model needs to be destroyed or hidden.